# Two distinct numbers are selected from $\{ 1, \dots , 100\}$. Find the probability that the larger of the two is more than 50 .

Tags: probability

If I take the condition that one number is greater than 50 and then calculate once for smaller number being less than 50 and once for smaller number being less than 50 and add them up is it correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question in further detail, yes you can do both ways -

If you want to count all positive cases then -

$P = \displaystyle \frac{{50 \choose 1} {50 \choose 1} + {50 \choose 2}}{100 \choose 2} = \frac{149}{198}$

The first part is for choosing one number between $1 - 50$ and the other between $51-100$. Second part is for choosing both numbers between $51-100$.

Other way to do it is -
$P = \displaystyle 1 - \frac{50 \choose 2}{100 \choose 2} = \frac{149}{198}$

Here you are finding the probability of both numbers being between $1 - 50$ and then subtracting from $1$ which will give probability of at least one of them being in $51 - 100$.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is ( assuming the numbers may be equal) : $1- \frac 12\cdot \frac 12=\frac 34$: the opposite event is when both numbers are $50$ or less. If the numbers are assumed to be different then the probability is $1-\frac 12\cdot \frac{49}{99}=\frac{149}{198}=0.75\overline{25}$.

Comment: But we need 2 distinct numbers

Comment: I have changed the answer.

Comment: Could you please explain the 2nd part where we assume the numbers to be different ?

Comment: The first number is chosen among $1,..., 50$, the probability of that is $50/100=1/2$. The second number is chosen among the first $49$. And there is a misprint: the denominator is $99$, not $100$. I have fixed it.

Comment: Hmm, I do not agree with that, if you chose $30,30$ you have them lower than $50,49$ yet equal. I think you have to calculate $1-p((x=y)\lor((x\le 50)\land(y\le 50)))$

Comment: You cannot choose the second $30$ because $30$ is gone.